# Lifetime mismatch between function in async trait and implementations

Tags: asynchronous, rust, trait-objects

## Background

I'm trying to create a trait object with a single associated function, but that function needs to be async. So, I've been trying to use the [`async_trait`](https://crates.io/crates/async-trait) crate to enable just that.

## Problem Statement

In my example below however, the compiler complains about mismatched lifetime parameters. For the life of me, I cannot figure out why this lifetime error appears. May I humbly ask for your input on the issue? Am I overlooking something obvious?

```
error[E0195]: lifetime parameters or bounds on method `run` do not match the trait declaration
  --> src/lib.rs:13:17
   |
9  |     async fn run(&mut self, res: &Resources, t: Duration, dt: Duration);
   |     -----    ---------------------------------------------------------- lifetimes in impl do not match this method in trait
   |     |
   |     this bound might be missing in the impl
...
13 |     async fn run(&mut self, _: &Resources, _: Duration, _: Duration)
   |                 ^ lifetimes do not match method in trait

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0195`.
error: could not compile `playground` (lib) due to 1 previous error
```

## Steps to Diagnose

Based on the documentation, I've gathered that `async_trait` adds additional lifetime parameters during expansion, but I'm not good with procedural macro code, so I wasn't able to figure out the exact used parameters and bounds from the code. Implementing the lifetime parameters from the example expansion (`AutoplayingVideo`) in the documentation didn't work.

## Minimal Reproducing Example

[Rust Playground Code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=010861b4929c8e3715fb9616e89a0664)

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use async_trait::async_trait;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Resources(Vec<usize>);

#[async_trait]
pub trait System {
    async fn run(&mut self, res: &Resources, t: Duration, dt: Duration);
}

impl System for () {
    async fn run(&mut self, _: &Resources, _: Duration, _: Duration) {}
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `#[async_trait]` annotation on the impl. The error is bad though.

Comment: I guess it was better a while ago, when `async fn` in traits wasn't stable... but it's stable now.

Comment: Thank you! That was an embarrassing oversight on my part.